# Magento2 order email date formatting

Tags: magento2, transactional-mail, date, locale

I'm trying to edit email template and format created date.
The date in the email is written using this variable

```
 {{var order.created_at}}
```

And I think that It is created using the following function of **vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php**

```
 /**
     * Get formatted order created date in store timezone
     *
     * @param int $format date format type (\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT|\IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM
     * |\IntlDateFormatter::LONG|\IntlDateFormatter::FULL)
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCreatedAtFormatted($format)
    {
        return $this->timezone->formatDateTime(
            new \DateTime($this->getCreatedAt()),
            $format,
            $format,
            $this->localeResolver->getDefaultLocale(),
            $this->timezone->getConfigTimezone('store', $this->getStore())
        );
    }
```

This function must read Locale (it_IT in my case)

```
        $this->localeResolver->getDefaultLocale(),
```

but the date is always formatted in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm

Is it correct?

I'd like to use italian version dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm, it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$originalDate = "2019-06-20";
echo "new date : ".$newDate = date("d-m-Y h:m", strtotime($originalDate));
```

Comment: I think I can't add php in transactional email! Is not so?